# how to find Imported web

Tags: 2007, migration, site-collection, import

I exported a web from a site collection and imported it to a newly created site collection but when I try to access it, I get 404.

My new site collection is,

```
https://2020.develop.com/custs/newsiteco
```

and I import a new web named as "abcdef"

```
https://2020.develop.com/custs/newsiteco/abcdef
```

or

```
https://2020.develop.com/custs/newsiteco/abcdef/default.aspx
```

it doesn't come up

**EDIT**

I used this tool

[spdeploymentwizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/)

Dunno what was the reason but I was trying to use a different web template then the one have been used for creating the Web/Site I am trying to move.

Comment: Can you see the subsite when you visit https://2020.develop.com/custs/newsiteco/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx?

Comment: No one really posts a question unless it's important. Please don't use URGENT in the title, as it is meaningless for posterity. People will help when they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) to check everything's where it should be.